# Angular JS hide first element of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How would I hide the first element of an ng-repeat?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-hide="true">
    <div>{{ item.value }}</div>
</div>
```

This works in that the whole ng-repeat block is hidden, but how would I hide only the first item in items? I want to display it completely differently using more prominent html/etc, so it's useful to have it in that list of data.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can do this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="!$first">
    <div>{{ item.value }}</div>
</div>
```

Here are the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Comment: You can also do ng-hide="$first" now as well.

Answer (score 8):

No need to hide, just use a filter to exclude the first item from the list:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items|filter:$index>0">
    <div>{{ item.value }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler solution in more recent versions of Angular.

The filter "limitTo" now supports a "begin" argument ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)):

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

So you can use it like this in a ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: items.length : 1"
```

This means that ng-repeat will begin at index 1 (instead of the default index 0) and will continue for the rest of the items array's length (which is less than items.length, but limitTo will handle that just fine).

Comment: Slick! Extra karma for linking to actual documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to skip last, use ng-if='!$last'.